# VHDL std_logic_vector conversion to signed and unsigned with numeric_std

Tags: vhdl, unsigned, signed

I have some doubts about the use of the conversions from `std_logic_vector` to `signed`/`unsigned`. I always use the conversion `signed(...)`, `unsigned(...)`, but when I try to use the conversions defined in the library `numeric_std` (`to_signed`, `to unsigned`), it doesn't work. Can someone explain to me why this happens? And why the conversion `unsigned()` and `signed()` works?

Answer (score 7):

Because the `std_logic_vector` and `signed`/`unsigned` types are closely related, you can use the typecast way to convert.  So `signed(a_std_logic_vector)` and `unsigned(a_std_logic_vector)` are okay.  However, the functions to convert are also defined in the standard.

Take a look at the [VHDL FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317021815/http://www.vhdl.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html#vec_conversion).
This is an old website from the days that newsgroups were still hot, but it still has plenty of good information about VHDL.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the package spec for numeric_std. You will find that to_signed converts to signed ... from integer.

As "vermaete" says, signed is a closely related type to std_logic_vector so you don't need a conversion function there.